# scorched3d not listed in Ubuntu software center

Tags: software-installation

Scorched3d not listed in Ubuntu software center. How can you i install. I have been trying everything that i can find. If it installs it will not launch.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 16.04.4LTS. It stopped running after in stalling  the new version.

Comment: You can use normal [comprehensive software manager](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/software-installation-on-modern-ubuntu/2555) as Muon or Synaptic, not Ubuntu/GNOME Software center (as you can see its useless for some applications). Or use `apt`/`apt-get`.